# How to combine these 2 queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Okay, so I have 2 queries, but I'm not sure how to merge them, here's the first one:

```
SELECT
    e.EmplName,
    CAST(SUM(t.ManHrs) AS REAL) AS [Hrs Logged]
FROM EmplCode e 
    LEFT JOIN TimeTicketDet t ON e.EmplCode = t.EmplCode
WHERE CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND t.WorkCntr <> 50
    AND e.DeptNum LIKE 'PROD %'
    AND e.Active = 'Y'
GROUP BY e.EmplName
HAVING CAST(SUM(t.ManHrs) AS REAL) < 6
```

So basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is compile a list of employees who log in under 6 hours a day.  The problem is, I'm unable to capture the employees who do not log in at all.  A LEFT JOIN to the EmplCode table doesn't work because

```
WHERE CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Essentially turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.  My query that lists all employees is this one:

```
SELECT
    e.EmplName
FROM EmplCode e
WHERE e.DeptNum LIKE 'PROD %'
    AND e.Active = 'Y'
GROUP BY e.EmplName
```

But having that ticketdate argument is what I'm having a hard time getting around.  How can I get a list of all employees and their log in time for today, while also including those who have no time tickets at all for today?  I tried doing  a subquery, but I just can't wrap my head around it when I filter for today's tickets only, without eliminating the nulls entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this: `CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` to the ON clause instead of the WHERE clause.

This too:    `AND t.WorkCntr <> 50`

The `HAVING` clause might also need to be modified, to include the employees who have no ManHrs.  Adding `OR SUM(t.ManHrs) IS NULL` to the end might do it, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: That's it!!! The HAVING clause was screwing me up.  I had actually already tried moving between the WHERE and ON clauses, so I thought that wasn't the answer, but it was indeed that, in combination with the HAVING clause.  Thanks

Comment: Dang, the new query takes just over 5 seconds to execute, seems insane for such a simple query

Answer (score 0):

`e` int the where is killing the `left`

```
SELECT
    e.EmplName,
    CAST(SUM(t.ManHrs) AS REAL) AS [Hrs Logged]
FROM EmplCode e 
    LEFT JOIN TimeTicketDet t 
      ON cast CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
     AND t.WorkCntr <> 50
where e.EmplCode = t.EmplCode
  AND e.DeptNum LIKE 'PROD %'
  AND e.Active = 'Y' 
GROUP BY e.EmplName
HAVING CAST(SUM(t.ManHrs) AS REAL) < 6
```